# How to JS Date Format

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable

I'm using Laravel 8 and Bootsrap in this project. I've tried to solve this problem with Carbon in Laravel, but the prob still likes that.

So I think maybe the problem in JS Script, but I dunno about JS so deep. I really need help with this prob.

My problem is how to change the date format in JS, I wish to change in DD/MM/YYYY format.

**JS Script**

```html
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#kategoris-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'kategori/json',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'nama', name: 'nama',
                fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    $(nTd).html("<a href='/kategoris/"+oData.id+"'>"+oData.nama+"</a>");
                }
            },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

**My Table View**
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code where you are displaying your date? Are you using a front-end framework such as Vue?

Comment: What is the problem? Can you [edit] the question to clarify?

Comment: @Andrew I already show it the code, only in JS code. I do and I using Bootstrap.

Comment: @andrewjames Okay done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this variable to the Model class:

```
protected $casts = [
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:m/d/Y'
];
```

This will change the datetime format and will reflect whenever you retrieve the data through eloquent.

Comment: Thank you, so glad to find this info. :)

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 2):

You could try registering an `editor` and using `moment.js`. Something like this:

```
var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY' );

    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: 'kategori/json',
        table: '#kategoris-table',
        fields: [ {
                label:  'Updated at:',
                name:   'updated_at',
                type:   'datetime',
                def:    function () { return new Date(); },
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                fieldInfo: 'Formatted date'
            }
        ]
    } );

    $('#kategoris-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'kategori/json',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'nama', name: 'nama',
                fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    $(nTd).html("<a href='/kategoris/"+oData.id+"'>"+oData.nama+"</a>");
                }
            },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
        ]
    });
});
```

Please see this example which includes the other libraries you would need to load at the end of the example: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/dates/formatting.html

PS - I tried to include the libraries in my answer in case of a broken link but when I do, I am given the message that "There appears to be code in my post that is not formatted properly" and I cannot seem to get it to work with formatting the links.